# How to set the name of the select input equal to the MenuItem

Tags: reactjs, drop-down-menu, material-ui

I have a Select Input with option list (MenuItem) that have values
I want the values  in my state so I can dispatch them to my Redux state later on
I've managed to get the right values in the right format into the state
but now the name of the option, when selected, 
does not display.
how do I handle the event the proper way?

```
const styles = theme => ({
  button: {
    display: 'block',
    marginTop: theme.spacing.unit * 2,
  },
  formControl: {
    margin: theme.spacing.unit,
    minWidth: 125,
  },
});

class ControlledOpenSelect extends React.Component {
  state = {
    sauce: '',
    saucePrice: 0,
    open: false,
  };

  handleChange = event => {
    const value = event.target.value.split(",")
    this.setState({
      sauce: value[0],
      saucePrice: parseFloat(value[1]),

     });


  };

  handleClose = () => {
    this.setState({ open: false });
  };

  handleOpen = () => {
    this.setState({ open: true });
  };

  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    console.log(this.state );

    return (
      <form autoComplete="off" className='pizzaSauce'>


        <FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
          <InputLabel htmlFor="openSelect">NewAge Sauce</InputLabel>
          <Select
            open={this.state.open}
            onClose={this.handleClose}
            onOpen={this.handleOpen}
            value={this.state.sauce}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            inputProps={{
              name: 'sauce',
              id: 'openSelect',
            }}
          >
            <MenuItem value="">
              <em>None</em>
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value={'white, 0.50'}>White Sauce &euro;1,00</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value={'red, 0.50'}>Red Sauce &euro;0,50</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value={'double, 0.50'}>Double red sauce &euro; 1,00</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value={'mix, 0.50'}>Mix it up! &euro; 1,50</MenuItem>

          </Select>
        </FormControl>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

ControlledOpenSelect.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default withStyles(styles)(ControlledOpenSelect);
```

Before this the handleChange()
looked like this

```
 handleChange = event => {
    this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you're trying to set a value to the `Select` of `'white'` when there's not `MenuItem` with value of `'white'`, but `'white, 0.50'`

Not surely know if its the best option, but you could try adding another property to your state like `selectedSauce` and make a setState to it of the whole `event.target.value`

Comment: well I didn't add another property to my state but did add another setState
  handleChange = event => {
    const value = event.target.value.split(",")
    this.setState({
      sauce: value[0],
      saucePrice: parseFloat(value[1]),

     });
 this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });

  };

That solved my Problem.